# JAVA LZW For Audio Compression

Tags: java, compression, wav, lzw

I am working on a project to compress WAV files using LZW compression.

I found this code and tried to modify it to handle the wav files,

However, two things are getting messed up:

1. The Compressed Audio file is no longer can be played by media players.
2. The code below I used, it works perfectly on text files. but fails on Wav files.

Your help is really appreciated.
(P.S the code below is from  https://code.google.com/p/lzwj/source/browse/src/main/java/by/dev/madhead/lzwj/compress/LZW.java?r=c834a12adea60b0a5d9c3fa3a9d7900c26e5df80)

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import by.dev.madhead.lzwj.io.Input;
import by.dev.madhead.lzwj.io.Output;
import by.dev.madhead.lzwj.util.ByteArray;

public class LZW {
        public static final int INITIAL_DICT_SIZE = 256; // 0..255
        public static final int DEFAULT_CODEWORD_LENGTH = 12; // Bit

        private int codeWordLength = DEFAULT_CODEWORD_LENGTH;
        private Map<ByteArray, Integer> codeTable;
        private List<ByteArray> decodeTable;

        public int getCodeWordLength() {
                return codeWordLength;
        }

        public void setCodeWordLength(int codeWordLength) {
                // Haha! Expected this method do something useful, didn't you?
                // this.codeWordLength = codeWordLength;
        }

        // Here be dragons!
        public void compress(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                init();

                int code = INITIAL_DICT_SIZE;

                InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(in);
                Output compressedOutput = new Output(new BufferedOutputStream(out),
                                codeWordLength);

                int firstByte = bufferedIn.read();
                ByteArray w = new ByteArray((byte) firstByte);
                int K;

                while ((K = bufferedIn.read()) != -1) {
                        ByteArray wK = new ByteArray(w).append((byte) K);
                        if (codeTable.containsKey(wK)) {
                                w = wK;
                        } else {
                                compressedOutput.write(codeTable.get(w));
                                if (code < (1 << codeWordLength) - 1) {
                                        codeTable.put(wK, code++);
                                }
                                w = new ByteArray((byte) K);
                        }
                }
                compressedOutput.write(codeTable.get(w));
                compressedOutput.flush();
                compressedOutput.close();
        }

        public void decompress(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                init();

                Input compressedInput = new Input(new BufferedInputStream(in),
                                codeWordLength);
                OutputStream bufferedOut = new BufferedOutputStream(out);

                int oldCode = compressedInput.read();
                bufferedOut.write(oldCode);
                int character = oldCode;
                int newCode;
                while ((newCode = compressedInput.read()) != -1) {
                        ByteArray string;
                        if (newCode >= decodeTable.size()) {
                                string = new ByteArray(decodeTable.get(oldCode));
                                string.append((byte) character);
                        } else {
                                string = decodeTable.get(newCode);
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < string.size(); i++) {
                                bufferedOut.write(string.get(i));
                        }
                        character = string.get(0);
                        decodeTable.add(new ByteArray(decodeTable.get(oldCode))
                                        .append((byte) character));
                        oldCode = newCode;
                }

                bufferedOut.flush();
                bufferedOut.close();
        }

        private void init() {
                codeTable = new HashMap<ByteArray, Integer>();
                decodeTable = new ArrayList<ByteArray>();
                for (int i = 0; i < INITIAL_DICT_SIZE; i++) {
                        codeTable.put(new ByteArray((byte) i), i);
                        decodeTable.add(new ByteArray((byte) i));
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you intend to compress a `WAV` file and have it still be playable afterwards?

Comment: Actually, the whole project is about steganography, The project goes as follows:
1. Embed Text into WAV file (STEGANO)(DONE).
2. Then have the file compressed using LZW.
3. Last, put the Compressed WAV file into another WAV file.

And yes, the file has to be playable. but for now, I just need to make the compression work fine.

Comment: Why? LZW is an ancient, relatively ineffective compression compression method. Java already has deflate and inflate as part of its standard libraries that works much better. Furthermore for audio you should consider lossy compression methods, which can compress much more than lossless methods such as LZW and deflate, but that can leave what is audible essentially indistinguishable from the original (depending on the bit rate).

Comment: You are right Mark, but this project is used as analysis, we will be using lossy of course, we just want to to submit the two codes, one is LZW, and other one is much more effective,

Comment: Did you ever found the solution ? I have the same problem with LZW compression on audio files. I made it with Node.js and I have the 2 same problems as you.